# Ruby runtime config variables or constants

Tags: ruby

I'm giving out a 'n' days free access to users when they sign up. Now I'd like to keep testing this value and would like to give out an interface for the admins so they can try it out without my intervention.

The obvious solution, atleast to me, was to define a new modal with a single field and retrieve the last value from this table.

```
class TrialTime
   include Mongoid::Document
   field :trial_time,  type: Integer
end
```

and something like `TimeTime.last.trial_time`, only this looks inefficient to me.

Somehow I feel that configuration variables would be a better fit here. But I could not figure out how to persist this. Or am I completely over thinking this and the basic DB based solution is the right one?

Comment: If you want to persist it and allow admins to change it and you already have a database then that seems like the place to put it.

Comment: Yeah, thought so too. I guess I'm overthinking this scenario.